# Testing anchor links call with Mocha & Sinon

Tags: javascript, bdd, mocha.js, sinon

I am writing a test case to spy on google tracking calls on click event. There are two scenarios covered in code. One, traverse all the hyperlinks on the page and call the click method inside the for loop. Second, write independent test cases for the individual elements.

```
describe("Container Tags Automated Test Suite", function() {

    var spy;
    var assert = sinon.assert;

    beforeEach(function() {
        spy = sinon.spy(window.spyConfig.object, window.spyConfig.method);
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        spy.restore();
    });

    // Trackable links & total links count
    var links = $("a.wrapper-link"),
        linksCount = links.length;

    //FIRST APPRAOCH : MAKE ARRAY OF LINKS
    for(var i=0; i < linksCount ; i++) {
        it ("Track All page links", function() {
            link = $(links[i]);
            link.click();
            assert.called(spy);
        }); 
    }

    //SECOND APPROACH : Invidual Selectors
    it ("Track single link", function() {
        link = $('a.wrapper-link');
        link.click();
        assert.called(spy);
    });

});
```

**Problem:** Everything is working fine if we use independent jquery selectors for each test case. For eg. test case "Track Single Link" got PASS on every execution.

But, with first approach to make an array on links and then bind click event to elements forcing the test case to FAIL. Trying hard from last couple of hours but didn't get any luck to find the root cause of this issue. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the common error with for loops where at the end `i === linksCount` when the test is running. You have to wrap the call to the test into function and passing `i` into it to save it in the scope of the function.

```
//FIRST APPRAOCH : MAKE ARRAY OF LINKS

for(var i=0; i < linksCount ; i++) {
    (function(cnt){
      it ("Track page the " + cnt + ". link", function() {
        link = $(links[cnt]);
        link.click();
        assert.called(spy);
      }); 
    })(i)
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot man, saved my day. If you don't mind, please share some useful blog links to read out more on this for loops issue. Many thanks again.